# Google apps : Unable to receive emails after changing hosting from godaddy to phpfog

Tags: domain-name-system

I have configured my email in google apps and it was working fine till I changed my hosting from Godaddy to phpfog. I have created a new wordpress site there and added an 'A' record for my root domain to the ip addresses specified by phpfog.
Now I am unable to receive emails from any in google apps mail, from accounts in yahoo, msn, etc. I am getting emails from gmail and google apps accounts.
Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Iy domain is `shameerc.com`

Answer (score 1):

Results for MX-records:

```
Pref    Hostname                    IP Address      TTL     
1       aspmx.l.google.com          74.125.65.27    8 hrs
5       alt1.aspmx.l.google.com     74.125.115.27   8 hrs
5       alt2.aspmx.l.google.com     173.194.66.27   8 hrs
10      aspmx2.googlemail.com       74.125.43.27    8 hrs
10      aspmx3.googlemail.com       74.125.127.27   8 hrs
30      aspmx4.googlemail.com       209.85.229.27   8 hrs
30      aspmx5.googlemail.com       74.125.157.27   8 hrs
```

Looks pretty good to me.

Maybe the DNS hasn't propagated to all the other DNS-servers.
Try finding a server nearby to compare:

```
dig shameerc.com MX
```