# after changing nameserver email not coming, Got domain from godaddy, site hosted on hostgator and gmail service from Google suite

Tags: hosting, mx-record, gmail, godaddy, email-bounces

We have developed a new site with external developer, and they have hosted website on hostgator.com
to host they have given names servers, in Godaddy manage DNS I have selected custom name server and put both the name servers,
now we have stop receiving email (google-email, suit)
If I select default nameserver- email starts working but website gets down,
we are struggling with this from last 1 week, 
any help much appreciated

Comment: Well, without seeing DNS records or the domain there is only one thing that can be suggested to you: Check your mx records.

Comment: what info you are expecting?, done MXLoookup and got this response https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XJQvQ7HCq2cXVzMEhqYXFrOTg/view?usp=sharing  from https://mxtoolbox.com site

Answer (score 4):

If you delegate nameservers then the full setup belongs to the delegated nameservers (hostgator in your setup) and they will need to setup MX records for you.

As, from your description it looks like a minimal setup, I would suggest you not to delegate nameservers but to setup A / CNAME records for your website and configure the remaining MX records as usual.

Practical infos:

- use your normal nameserver from godaddy.
- point www to godaddy. You can do this by assigning an A record to an IP provided by your programmers or by a CNAME to an hostname, also provided by your programmers.
- configure google MX records as following:

record type / priority / hostname

MX  1   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

MX  5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

MX  5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

MX  10  ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

MX  10  ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have very limited idea about hosting, tried https://support.google.com/a/answer/6151550?hl=en  and https://serverfault.com/questions/340828/google-apps-unable-to-receive-emails-after-changing-hosting-from-godaddy-to-ph MX settings, but nothing seems work

Comment: i've tried to make it simpler

Comment: Thank you Federico, I have done MX part. 
1) use your normal nameserver from hostgator - okay will add nameserver provided by vendor. <br>
2) www to gadaddy means?, A record already has some IP address.

Comment: Excuse me, you were originally on godaddy and you should revert back to stock godaddy settings. Then apply changes and pointings to A CNAME and MX records

Comment: Thanks Federio, I have set default name servers, added MX entries, and got Host IP from developer and added IP as A Name,
tested DNS lookup https://mxtoolbox.com so it started showing Domain name, but when I hit site it doesn't opening.

Comment: Don't forget to allow some time for dns propagation. Is your website hosted on a vps or on some hosting platform? (I've seen that hostgator allows both) . If it's the second case, please consider use CNAME.

Comment: Thank you so much Man, that is working, the developer given correct IP details, now it working fine.

Comment: We were so close! :-)